# Error loading JQueryUI 1.10.3 in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am loading jQuery UI from google's cdn. It works in every browser that I have to support (IE8+) except IE9. I'm getting a strange error on page load in the jQuery UI code at this line (line 249 in the unminified version):

```
$.support.selectstart = "onselectstart" in document.createElement( "div" );
```

The error is:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'createElement'
```

The code to include it is

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
```

I've looked at the 'document' object in the debugger, and it appears to have createElement defined (as expected).

Comment: Maybe you have `document` overridden with a local variable? Try to include only jQuery UI script and see if problem remains.

Comment: I'll try that, though I expect it would cause problems in other browsers. I've been wrong before though!

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to 1.10.2 or .1 ?

Comment: Just tried both above solutions, no luck so far, though I appreciate the ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally discovered the problem. I have no idea why it's happening, but for some reason there is a scoping issue document in IE9 isn't the document you'd expect it to be.

The behavior can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/esn2v/8/

```
with(block = document.createElement('div')) {
    with(detaildiv = document.createElement('div')) {
        alert('test');
    }
}
```

It works fine in any browser except IE9. If you open it in IE9 no alert happens, and you can look at the console to see an error regarding document.

It doesn't happen if you just include jquery and jquery UI like here: http://jsfiddle.net/uRFz5/

```
<script src=
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My app must just be a perfect storm that causes this issue to happen.

Comment: +1 for coming back and answering your own question a month later.